# Using/attaching ngChange directive from inside controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Total angular noob here, so perhaps a stupid question - is it possible to somehow use ngChange  directive from inside controller, without defining it in the template?

What I really want is to be able to listen to user triggered change events on the inputs in the controller, but on my case, using `$watch` will not work because it will respond to all changes (whether they were made by the user or not).

Comment: Interesting question.  Why can't you define it on the template?

Comment: The reason is simple - the template can be customized by the application user and I'd rather have as little logic in the template as possible, so that the user can't break too much.

Comment: Understood but the user can essentially kill your app if they can customize the template. You may want to look into a directive but again the user could manipulate the HTML and break it. Kind of a moot point.

Comment: Post some sample code to determine if there is a way to help you.  My only thought is you could create a directive that goes on a wrapping element for the input that isn't editable by a user and that directive could add an ng-change to the input.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Perhaps it's easier to add a custom element/directive, something like `<myinput>` rather that let the user  be concerned about the input and it's attributes.

Comment: That's absolutely a route you can go, but like I said if the user can edit the html they could possibly change it to `<yourInput>`.  If the user editable part is wrapped in something they can't edit, that wrapper can apply via a directive an `ng-change` to the input.  Give some code a shot and then ask some questions about the code.